# Как обработать запрос к несуществующему серверу

Tags: android

При запросе к реальному серверу всё работает, могу получить код ответа. Как получить хоть какой то ответ, если сервера просто нет? Логи в таком случае вообще не выводятся.

```
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(URL);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                        connection.connect();
                        Log.d("MyLog", "Message = " + connection.getResponseMessage());
                        Log.d("MyLog", "Code = "+connection.getResponseCode());
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: а ошибку то дает. или ошибку тоже не дает?

Comment: логи не выводятся потому, что возникает `Exception`, который отлавливается блоком `catch() {}`. в этот блок вы и попадете. Там и делайте то ,что надо в случае *несуществующего сервера*